# In android, Can we perform periodic API calls directly from the widget itself

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm working on an Android widget that needs to display Integer data fetched periodically from a REST API. I'm wondering if there's a way to initiate these API calls directly from the widget even when the corresponding app is not in background.

I have looked into AlarmManager and JobScheduler but I'm not sure if these are the best practices for widgets.

I am facing issues with Understanding the best method to perform network calls for widgets without draining the battery.The widget should update with new data from the API every hour.

Can anyone provide guidance or code examples on the recommended way to achieve this in Android?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.